# Displaying a String from one web-form to another

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am storing some value in the string in a webform and displaying it on another webform. I am doing it right but it's not working. Please help me to get rid of this problem.
Here is my code for the source page.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url;
    url = "backend.aspx?name=" + TextBox1.Text;
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

Here is my Destination page code.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["name"];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url;
    url = "backend.aspx?name=" + Server.UrlEncode(TextBox1.Text);
    Response.Redirect(url);
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Label1.Text = Request.Params["name"];
 }
```